# Why ZADD command not working in Django-app?

Tags: django, redis, django-redis

I want to realize in my Django blog «Top 5 trend post».

For this purpose, I implemented a Cron task that calls the function **update_trends()** once a day.

This function should **reset hits counter in Redis db**.

**Hits counter is a Sorted Set** with the structure: setname ("hits") score (hits amount) key (post id)

Here is the function:

```
import redis
from .models import Article

r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

def update_trends():

    # deleting the counter with click statistics for the previous day
    r.delete('hits')

    # Assigning a zero value for each post id
    articles_ids = Article.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True)
    for article_id in articles_ids:
        r.zadd('hits', 0, article_id)
```

When Cron fires, the sorted set "hits" is removed, but for some reason zero values ​​for each post id are not written.

I can't understand why?

If I manually write in shell:

```
redis-cli zadd hits 0 1
```

Then the value is successfully set.

Also I have tried to use in update_trends() such way:

```
articles = Article.objects.all()
for article in articles:
    r.zadd('hits', 0, article.pk)
```

But it doesn't work too.